# Concatenate indeterminate number of elements in a character vector into a single string in R

Tags: r, string, concatenation

I have a character vector, p, which may have seven or more elements.  For example, here there are 8 elements:

```
  > p  
  [1] "15"        "10.698"    "VB"        "0.0257"    "209.67235" "2.8164"    "1,8"       "cineole"
```

I want to combine all elements after the seventh into a single string.  In the above instance,

```
> paste(p[7],p[8])   
[1] "1,8 cineole"
```

gives the desired output.  However,

```
  > paste(p[c(7:length(p))])  
[1] "1,8"     "cineole"
```

does not, which means if there are 9 or more elements in p, it wont work.  I've tried various other ways of combining these elements, eg toString(), which adds unwanted commas, and cat(), which gives the right output but doesn't seem capable of referring its output to a new variable. (eg:

```
  > name<-cat(p[c(7:length(p))])  
1,8 cineole  
> name  
NULL
```

How can I combine an indeterminate (i.e 2 or more) number of character elements into a single string?

Note, I'm doing this iteratively, where p is a line imported from a pdf file and there may be hundreds of lines on each pdf, and there are over 2000 pdfs.  So I can't manually adjust for longer vectors of p in specific cases.  My objective ultimately is to combine all the relevant lines from all pdfs into a single dataframe.

Comment: `paste0(p[7:length(p)], collapse=" ")`.  Details in the online doc.

Comment: Nope, that doesn't work either.  I need a single string, not a new vector of strings.
> paste0(p[7:length(p)],sep=" ")
  [1] "1,8 "     "cineole "

Comment: Apologies.  Edited.

Comment: Great, that seems to work, thanks.  I didn't realise that collapse was different to sep.  If you want to put your response as an answer I'll mark it as the accepted response.